# Email Validation Function kicking up error

Tags: php, email-validation

I have been upgrading from PHP 4 to PHP 5.7 and I have a function that I have been working on:

```
function is_valid_email($email) {
   // First, we check that there's one @ symbol, and that the lengths are right
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  // Email invalid because wrong number of characters in one section, or wrong number of @ symbols.
return false;
}
// Split it into sections to make life easier
$email_array = explode("@", $email);
$local_array = explode(".", $email_array[0]);
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($local_array); $i++) {
  if (!preg_match("/[^A-Za-z'-]/",$local_array($i))) {
  return false;
  }
}
if (!preg_match("^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$",'/' . $email_array[1])) { // Check if domain is IP. If not, it should be valid domain name
  $domain_array = explode(".", $email_array[1]);
  if (sizeof($domain_array) < 2) {
  return false; // Not enough parts to domain
  }
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($domain_array); $i++) {
    if (!preg_match("^(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])|([A-Za-  z0-9]+))$", '/' . $domain_array[$i])) {
    return false;
    }
  }
}
return true;
}
```

When the form is submitted I get this error:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /usr/local/www/panhistoria/MyBooks/email_alert.php on line 241

Line 241 is the first `!preg_match`

Comment: just use the internal function `if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ ` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$local_array($i)` is an array, not a function, so it needs to be addressed with `[]`, or `{}`.

So try:

```
if (!preg_match("/[^A-Za-z'-]/",$local_array[$i])) {
```

For more information on accessing arrays see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

From the manual:

> Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements.

Also your later regexs also are missing [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

For example your second `preg_match` should be:

```
preg_match("/^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$/"
```

If you need to use a modifier it would go after the second `/`. If a `/` needed to be used in the expression you could either escape it or change the delimiter. Escaping would be `\/`. As a different delimiter:

```
preg_match("~^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$~"
```

You also should work on indenting every control block.

Comment: Ok - great, I totally missed that! But I'm having trouble understanding delimiters - are they the slash marks? Where is the correct place to put them?

Comment: Added a couple examples of delimiter usage.